# Is there a way to eliminate reduncancy in this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, optimization

I have a bunch of Jquery that replaces the content of DivA with the content of either DivB, DivC, DivD depending on whether li1, li2 or li3 is clicked.

However, the Jquery is essentially the same piece of code repeated for every single replaceable element.

So, if I have 2 sections on a page, each with 3 sections of content to choose from, the Jquery code gets very long.

Is there a way to strip this down but still keep the same functionality?

This is the code for each li -

```
$('.1').click(function () {
    $('.mainDescription').fadeOut(400, function () {
        $('.mainDescription').html($('#desc1').html()).fadeIn(200);
    });
    $('.mainImage').fadeOut(400, function () {
        $('.mainImage').html($('#desc1Image').html()).fadeIn(200);
    });
})
```

.1 is the class of the li that is clicked on.

.mainDescription is the Div in which the visibile text content appears.

.mainImage is the Div in which the visible image appears.

Div #desc1 is the hidden div that the text content is pulled from when .li1 is clicked.

Div #desc1Image is the hidden div that the image content is pulled from when /li1 is clicked.

A full working example can be found here...

https://jsfiddle.net/qeq82y42/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this works.

https://jsfiddle.net/nyxeen/qeq82y42/9/

I did some changes so that your li elements have all information needed to add the image and the description. So when you click on an li it takes the information from that li and post it into your div. So you need only one function and no hidden divs.

**Explanation**:
If you add an event to an element you can refer to that element inside of the function as 'this'. So if you add the same event to multiple elements, you still know exactly who triggered it by using 'this'. Since your li elements already know the image(they contain the same), you can just take that information without creating a hidden div. But your li elements don't know the description and the name of the target div. So i added these informations.

Edit: I changed it so that you can have multiple divs like in your example.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.clickable').click(function () {
              var src=$(this).children("img").attr("src");
                var des=$(this).children("img").attr("data-desk");
                var tar=$(this).children("img").attr("data-target");
                $('.'+tar+'Description').fadeOut(400, function () {
                    $('.'+tar+'Description').html(des).fadeIn(200);
                });
                $('.'+tar+'Image').fadeOut(400, function () {
                    $('.'+tar+'Image').html('<img src="'+src+'">').fadeIn(200);
                });
            })
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 500px;
}
img{width:100%;height:auto;}
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 500px;
}

.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.col-xs-6 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.col-xs-12 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <ul>
        <li class="clickable"><img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/abstract-colourful-cool-wallpapers-55ec7905a6a4f.jpg" class="img-responsive" data-desk="Description 1" data-target="main"></li>
        <li class="clickable"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRfs21_S1c5l_qDHy9PEyrlXLh75CChSVTpu3B3JjoV5kdQ_XXj" class="img-responsive"  data-desk="Description 2" data-target="main"></li>
        <li class="clickable"><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/ef/9c/22/ef9c22cd9f1030edb2b21883b5fbe0d8.jpg" class="img-responsive"  data-desk="Description 3" data-target="main"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 mainImage">
      <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/abstract-colourful-cool-wallpapers-55ec7905a6a4f.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 mainDescription">
      <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc varius convallis elit non mollis. In pharetra orci eget mollis commodo
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome and I really appreciate the explanation but I can't seem to get it to work if I duplicate the divs, when I click one of the li's, it changes the main image and description in both divs.

https://jsfiddle.net/qeq82y42/7/

Comment: your img in your li has a data-target attribute. It refers to the the div it uses. data-target="main" uses the mainDescription div. data-taget="main2" would use a div main2Description. Same for the Image div.
https://jsfiddle.net/nyxeen/qeq82y42/8/

Comment: I also made a little mistake in my fist post. fixed it. You shound't just copy that code, you should try to understand what it does so that you can recreate it.

Comment: Ah I get it now, and yeh I'm definitely not just copying, I'm playing with it but couldn't figure that bit out despite it being obvious now. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that does this job for you and call this function with the Jquery selectors passed in.

for ex.

```
 function customFade(description, newDesc, image, newImage) {
    $(description).fadeOut(400, function() {
      $(description).html($(newDesc).html()).fadeIn(200);
    });
    $(image).fadeOut(400, function() {
      $(image).html($(newImage).html()).fadeIn(200);
    });
  }
```

and call it like this

```
customFade('.mainDescription2','#desc32','.mainImage2','#desc3Image2');
```

Comment: You still have to bind it to a click event :). Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/qeq82y42/5/

Answer (score 1):

One of the simple way is to use their className.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shubham_agr10/7pfLy52w/)**

I have only updated the fiddle for `description#1`.You can do in similar manner for the rest.

Like this:

```
  $('.1,.2,.3').click(function() {
    var myVar = $(this).attr("class");
    $('.mainDescription').fadeOut(400, function() {
      $('.mainDescription').html($('#desc' + myVar).html()).fadeIn(200);
    });
    $('.mainImage').fadeOut(400, function() {
      $('.mainImage').html($('#desc' + myVar + 'Image').html()).fadeIn(200);
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function and use it:

```
var bindFading = function(sourceElem, targetElem){
  sourceElem.fadeOut(400, function () {
    sourceElem.html(targetElem.html()).fadeIn(200);
  });
};

$('.1').click(function () {
  bindFading($('.mainDescription'), $('#desc1'));
  bindFading($('.mainImage'), $('#desc1Image'));
});
$('.2').click(function () {
  bindFading($('.mainDescription'), $('#desc2'));
  bindFading($('.mainImage'), $('#desc2Image'));
})
$('.3').click(function () {
  bindFading($('.mainDescription'), $('#desc3'));
  bindFading($('.mainImage'), $('#desc3Image'));
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qeq82y42/4/

Or you could write a small jquery plugin like:

```
$.fn.fading = function(targetElem){
    return this.each(function(){
     $(this).fadeOut(400, function () {
       $(this).html(targetElem.html()).fadeIn(200);
     });
  });
};

$('.1').click(function () {           
  $('.mainDescription').fading($('#desc1'));
  $('.mainImage').fading($('#desc1Image'));
})
$('.2').click(function () {
  $('.mainDescription').fading($('#desc2'));
  $('.mainImage').fading($('#desc2Image'));
})
$('.3').click(function () {
  $('.mainDescription').fading($('#desc3'));
  $('.mainImage').fading($('#desc3Image'));
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qeq82y42/3/